# Concourse: What is the difference between "Resource Types" and "Resource"?

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

When i developing pipeline i can't understand the difference between "Resource Types" and "Resource".
According to documentation Resource type is there only to provide the type of the resource and check for the tags. Like in example bellow:

```
---
resource_types:
- name: rss
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: suhlig/concourse-rss-resource
    tag: latest

resources:
- name: booklit-releases
  type: rss
  source:
    url: http://www.qwantz.com/rssfeed.php

jobs:
- name: announce
  plan:
  - get: booklit-releases
    trigger: true
```

Why do we need both of them? isn't it enough just to use resources?

Answer (score 3):

I'm also new to this project. Please correct me if I am wrong.
I think in the term of the container:
A `resource type` is an image and we need to config the repository and tag in its `source` so that the `concourse` can locate/download it.
A `resource` is a container which is an instance of that image and can be used in the `jobs` when the pipeline is running. Its `source` that we configure is the common parameters which will be passed on the stdin to the `check`, `in` and `out` scripts when the resource is configured in a `get` or `put` step.
I think it's a little similar to the comparison between the `class` and `object`.

Comment: This makes sence. tnx.